# How can I update Security Protocol to TLS 1.2 at run time

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tls1.2, cas

Not able to update the security protocol using the below code called in Application_Start of Global.asax, (Probably because the CAS communication is failing well before reaching this line of code)

`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;`

I have my .net application developed in 4.0 framework which is expected to use security protocol earlier than TLS 1.2. I have got a CAS authentication failing to redirect to my application due to TLS issue. To resolve this issue I did made a targeted framework change in web.config as below.

`<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" targetFramework="4.6" />`

But above solution is leading to different problems. So right now what I'm trying to figure out is to resolve my CAS issue by using Security Protocol update to 1.2. Please help me how can I deal with my situation.

Comment: Have you installed .NET 4.5 on the machine? You don't need to upgrade the project but you need to install .NET 4.5 runtime otherwise .NET won't know what (SecurityProtocolType)3072 means

Comment: @RickyStam Thanks for your response. I'm currently using Visual Studio 2010, which does not allow to install 4.0 higher versions. And more over I seriously doubt there will be many functional problems across my application on upgrading/installing. Now what I'm strictly looking for is, how can I set SecurityProtocol to TLS 1.2, at run time.

Answer (score 0):

If .NET 4.5 or greater is installed on your system the code you have posted: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;` should work without changing the .NET framework your application is targeting.

If you cannot upgrade the .NET framework on your system you will need to set the SchUseStrongCrypto and SystemDefaultTlsVersions registry keys to 1.

From:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls

> **For .NET Framework 3.5 - 4.5.2 and not WCF**
>
> We recommend you upgrade your app to .NET Framework 4.7 or later versions. If you cannot upgrade, take the following steps. At some point in the future, your application may fail until you upgrade to .NET Framework 4.7 or later versions.
>
> Set the [SchUseStrongCrypto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#schusestrongcrypto) and [SystemDefaultTlsVersions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#systemdefaulttlsversions) registry keys to 1. See Configuring security via the Windows Registry. The .NET Framework version 3.5 supports the SchUseStrongCrypto flag only when an explicit TLS value is passed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will give this a try.